How to get AWS SES Ip range
How can I get the outbound IP range for AWS SES in eu-west-1 region. How often do the IP range changes. I need it to help my server whitelist them for dynamic email sending with SMTP.

Might help: Amazon SES IP addresses | AWS Messaging & Targeting Blog

@JohnRotenstein yeah, thanks. I tried too, but the blog post is from 25 JUN 2013 and those IP are very much changed by now

You can run the dig TXT amazonses.com +short| grep 'v=spf1' command mentioned in the blog to retrieve the latest IP addresses: "v=spf1 ip4:199.255.192.0/22 ip4:199.127.232.0/22 ip4:54.240.0.0/18 ip4:69.169.224.0/20 ip4:23.249.208.0/20 ip4:23.251.224.0/19 ip4:76.223.176.0/20 ip4:54.240.64.0/19 ip4:54.240.96.0/19 ip4:76.223.128.0/19 ip4:216.221.160.0/19 ip4:206.55.144.0/20 -all"

Not sure about SES, but you can try your luck here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/aws-ip-ranges.html

I have check the ip-range.json file, it did not include SES IPs
